# libapt-private error occured while building a container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, ros

I am trying to build a container where command states like this

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.1-cudnn7-devel
.
.
.
COPY --from=nvidia/opengl:1.0-glvnd-runtime-ubuntu18.04 \
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu \
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

RUN apt-get update
```

When this line is running then I get the following error

```
Step 8/61 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Running in cfa6292dfdb5
apt-get: relocation error: apt-get: symbol _Z15InstallPackagesR9CacheFilebbb version APTPRIVATE_0.0 not defined in file libapt-private.so.0.0 with link time reference
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 bionic beaver and libapt-pkg5.0_1.6.14 is the libapt version. Running with NVIDIA 470 driver with CUDA 11.

I am not able to find libapt-private anywhere and also could not download it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The error basically means `libapt-private.so.0` is corrupt or something, but without debugging details, that's pretty much the end of it. Are you running on the right CPU architecture?

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer. Yes I am running it on the right CPU. Apt is corrupting inside docker container. All commands before that OpenGL working fine and even I make use of apt there and that’s working fine. Whenever it passes through this command, it’s somehow corrupting apt.

Comment: I think it's fair to assume that you are corrupting `x86_64-linux-gnu` which is responsible for resolving this and many other symbols. Where did you get this file, and are you sure it's compatible with the binary architecture of your container?  Where did you obtain this file?

Comment: hi @tripleee , its developed from one of my colleague. As of now, I am commenting the copying of OpenGL files from system to docker container and its being built and running fine. But could not find out why copying files from the local system to docker is causing an error.

Comment: The symptoms would suggest a binary incompatibility. Without knowledge about how the binary was made or how the Docker image is being run, there's not much more we can say.

Comment: I will have look into it again and see. thank you for the help @tripleee .